# Arranging letter with restriction

Tags: permutations, combinations

Need to find the the number of ways to arrange letter for below condition.
first letter cannot be placed in first or last position.
repetition is allowed, however letter cannot be repeated in adjacent positions.
I need logic for n letter in n position.

Example: 
3 letter  set {a,b,c} in 3 position
"a" cannot be put in  first or last position.
you cannot put two consecutive letter as repetition as ( b b c).
so possible values for 3 letter to be arranged in 3 position.

c a b

c b c

c a c

b a c

b a b

b c b

Answer : No of ways = 6.

Comment: please explicitly state your question

Comment: This might be helpful- http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457652/complex-permutation/1457665#1457665

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 choices for your first letter: $b$ or $c$.

Then you have 2 choices for your next letter: $a$ or [whichever of $b$ or $c$ was not the first letter]. Let's consider these two cases separately.

(1) $a$ was chosen for the middle. Then we have 2 choices for the final letter: $b$ or $c$.

(2) $a$ was not chosen for the middle. Then we are forced to use whichever letter was not used for the middle ($b$ or $c$).

This gives us: $2(1\cdot 2 + 1\cdot 1) = 6$ possible answers.

Notice the multiplication as we stack one choice on top of another and the addition when we must branch out to different possibilities.

Comment: Hmmm, $a$, should be the middle letter as it cannot be first nor last. Furthermore $b$'s and $c$'s may be used more than once.

Comment: Can we come up with generic solution , what will be case for 4 letters 4 position ( =60 ), 4 letter 5 position ? The solution above by Bill Cook is correct. Thanks.